# Page context not the same when going through even handler call stack?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Disclaimer: Not sure I'm asking the question correctly.

Given an ASP.NET page with the following functions:

```
 protected void Order_Shipped()
 {
  RegisterScript("Shipped");
 }

 protected void DDL_OrderStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  RegisterScript("Not Shipped");
  Order.Status = DDL_OrderStatus.SelectedValue;
 }

 protected void RegisterScript(string value)
 {
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "Blarg" + value, "alert('" + value + "');", true); 
 }
```

The Order.Status accessor has an event handler attached to it that calls Order_Shipped() on page.

Basically, when the order gets marked as shipped, it calls back to the function on page.

Order Class has the following:

```
 private string _Status;
  public string Status
  {
   get { return _Status; }
   set 
   { 
    _Status = value != null ? value.Trim() : value;
    if(value != null && value.Contains("Shipped"))
    {
     On_Shipped();
    }
   }
  }

......

  public delegate void Del_Shipped();
  private event Del_Shipped _Shipped;
  public event Del_Shipped Shipped
  {
   add
   {
    if(_Shipped == null || !_Shipped.GetInvocationList().Contains(value))
    {
     _Shipped += value;
    }
   }
   remove
   {
    _Shipped -= value;
   }
  }
  protected virtual void On_Shipped()
  {
   if(_Shipped != null)
   {
    _Shipped.Invoke();
   }
  }
```

The event handler is attached to the object on page load.

The event handler function RegisterScript(...) is being called twice. Once directly from the on page function and another time via the Order class event delegate.

With a debugger attached, I can verify that RegisterScript(..) does get called twice with the correct values.

However, the only alert that pops up is "Not Shipped" even though the alert for "Shipped" is being registered via the ScriptManager.

Looking at the call stack, the DDL_OrderStatus_SelectedIndexChanged is at the bottom with RegisterScript(..) at the top in both cases.

The difference seems to be in the HttpContext or Page. It's as if the Page instance being referenced is NOT the same in both call stacks even though both call stacks originate with DDL_OrderStatus_SelectedIndexChanged.

Does anyone have any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The event handler was being registered inside a !Page.IsPostBack block. This means that the event handler was registered to the old page which was not the same one as it is AFTER postback. Even though the function was being called, it was being called on a "dead" version of the page and hence not showing the alert. I hope this helps someone.